# How does JVM manage "this" reference?

Tags: java

I have edited this question three times and it's the final version.

How does JVM manage "this" reference?

You can find the answer in @still_learning's comment.

Comment: You are overthinking it, what with referring to the heap and all. `class` is an abstract construct; an instance of it is a realization - and you can have one or more, as many as you like. `this` points to the class instance you are working with.

Comment: Basically, the caller pushes the object reference onto the stack (not talking about the heap here!), the virtual machine invokes the method and provides the reference to the object (`this`), which the method was invoked on, as a local variable for the callee.

Comment: @RadLexus Hi, I'm not overthinking it I'm just trying to understand it ;)

Comment: @still_learning That's reasonable. You mean JVM always knows the base address of current object on heap and pass it to called function (using stack) as an extra argument. You sure about that?

Comment: @Shahin Yes, I am. Assume you are calling the method `object.foo(50)` of the class `com.example.MyObject`. Your code will be compiled to 1. push the reference to `object` onto the stack, 2. push the value `50` onto the stack (e.g. using `ldc`), 3. call the method `com/example/MyObject/foo(I)V`. Note that the actual method invocation does not contain the reference to `object`. The virtual machine gets the reference from the stack and provides it to the callee on its own stack such that the first parameter is the object reference (`this`) and the second parameter is the integer (`50`).

Comment: @still_learning Thanks. So my understanding was totally wrong, I should edit the question cause it may be misleading for other newbies in its current form. Anyway I really appreciate your help...